# How to permanent change html text after a submitted has been triggered

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently trying to find out if its possible to change a text in extension when a submit has happend. I currently have a text saying "ENTER DISCORD USER ID AND SUBMIT" and when an user has entered its USER ID and submitted, the text should be changed to "USER ID SUBMITTED" and the text should always say that afterwards, meaning that if someone closes and opens the extensions - the text should still say "USER ID SUBMITTED".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <form id="form" class="form-control mt10">
            <label> <input type="number" id="discord-id-input" name="discord-id-input"></label>
            <button id="discord-id-button" type="submit" class="submit"></button>
            <output id="help-text" class="help-text" value="">ENTER DISCORD USER ID AND SUBMIT</output>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
function get_discord_id(callback) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["discord_id"], (result) => {
        callback(result.discord_id);
    });
}

function set_discord_id(discord_id) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ discord_id: discord_id }, () => {});
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    // check if discord ID is already stored
    get_discord_id((discord_id) => {
        if (discord_id == null) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
                let value = document.getElementById("discord-id-input").value;

                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ discord_id: value }, function(response) {});

                set_discord_id(value);
                document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'USER ID SUBMITTED';
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    });
});
```

I wonder how I am able to permanent change a text after a submitted trigger has happend?

Comment: `form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); .... existing code`

Comment: Hi @Bravo - Im not sure if I follow?...

Comment: when a form submits a new page is loaded

Comment: @Bravo So if I just add your snippet, I would see the message even if I re-open the extension?

Comment: oh, didn't understand you wanted to make a persistent change to the page - not sure you can do that with an extension - where do you intend on storing this change?

Comment: @Bravo Thats a question that I do not have an answer on. Perhaps variable? I will accept any suggestions 

Comment: You need to keep a record stored, something like `{submitted: true}`. You can store it with either `chrome.storage.sync` or `chrome.storage.local`. Everytime the extension is opened you try to retrieve the value from storage, if it's present then you change the text to USER ID SUBMITTED.

Comment: Just took a closer look at your code and I see you're already storing and retrieving the `discord_id` with `chrome.storage.sync`. So, you just need to change the text if the `discord_id` is present. I'll provide the code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already store the `discord_id` and retrieve it when the popup window is opened, you can determine whether the id has been submitted based on the presents of `discord_id`.

Here is the updated JS code to do that

```
function get_discord_id(callback) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["discord_id"], (result) => {
        callback(result.discord_id);
    });
}

function set_discord_id(discord_id) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ discord_id: discord_id }, () => {});
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    // check if discord ID is already stored
    get_discord_id((discord_id) => {
        if (discord_id) {
           document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'USER ID SUBMITTED';
        } else {
            form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
                let value = document.getElementById("discord-id-input").value;

                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ discord_id: value }, function(response) {});

                set_discord_id(value);
                document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'USER ID SUBMITTED';
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: This was exactly how I wanted it to be! You are awesome. Wish you a happy weekend!